# RestKit addConnectionForRelationship not recognizing the connection

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have an RKEntitiyMapping object that maps an object that has a one-to-one relation to a child.

when calling the following code:

`[sessionMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"dailyGoalDetail" connectedBy:@{ @"dailyGoalDetailId": @"dailyGoalDetailId" }];`

and debugging throught the addConnectionForRelationship method, I see that the connection being added to the collection of connections is nil.
I double checked by finding the connection with Core Data this way:

`NSEntityDescription *parentEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:[MGRModel sharedModel].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    NSRelationshipDescription *childRelationship = [parentEntity relationshipsByName][@"dailyGoalDetail"];
    [sessionMapping addConnectionForRelationship:childRelationship connectedBy:@{@"dailyGoalDetailId":@"dailyGoalDetailId"}];`

And logging to console my relationship shows it. But the addConnectionForRelationship method still adds a nil connection to its collection.

What's wrong with this?

**Update**

Here's the relevant code of my Session object:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)responseMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping* sessionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectStore:[[MGRModel sharedModel] managedObjectStore]];
    [sessionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                         @"ActivityId": @"activityType",
                                                         @"DailyGoalDetailId": @"dailyGoalDetailId",
                                                         @"DeviceGuid": @"deviceId",
                                                         @"DeviceSessionId": @"entityId",
                                                         @"Frequency": @"frequency",
                                                         @"Pace": @"pace",
                                                         @"Start": @"start",
                                                         @"Stop": @"stop",
                                                         @"TotalBeats": @"totalBeats",
                                                         @"TotalKcal": @"totalCalories",
                                                         }];
    sessionMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"entityId" ];

    // Add relationship mapping with Measurement as "sessionDetails"
    [sessionMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"SessionDetails"
                                                                                   toKeyPath:@"sessionDetails"
                                                                                 withMapping:[MGRMeasurement responseMapping]]];

    NSEntityDescription *parentEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:[MGRModel sharedModel].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
    NSRelationshipDescription *childRelationship = [parentEntity relationshipsByName][@"dailyGoalDetail"];
    [sessionMapping addConnectionForRelationship:childRelationship connectedBy:@{@"dailyGoalDetailId":@"dailyGoalDetailId"}];

//    [sessionMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"dailyGoalDetail" connectedBy:@{ @"dailyGoalDetailId": @"dailyGoalDetailId" }];

    return sessionMapping;
}
```

And here's a po of the relationship:

```
(lldb) po childRelationship
(<NSRelationshipDescription: 0xc266570>), name dailyGoalDetail, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Session, renamingIdentifier dailyGoalDetail, validation predicates (
), warnings (
), versionHashModifier (null)
 userInfo {
}, destination entity DailyGoalDetail, inverseRelationship sessions, minCount 0, maxCount 1, isOrdered 0, deleteRule 1
```

Some more information. The JSON is like this:

```
{
  "DailyGoalDetails": [
    {
      "DailyGoal": {
        "ActivityUnit": {
          "ActivityUnitId": 1,
          "Name": "BEATS"
        },
        "DailyGoalId": 1,
        "ActivityUnitId": 1,
        "Name": "Un inizio facile",
        "Beats": 25,
        "Level": 1
      },
      "DailyGoalDetailId": 6,
      "DailyGoalId": 1,
      "UserId": "7a2e5b7c-9a3a-4ad1-ad79-946bcf2bf2f3",
      "Hit": true,
      "Value": 9,
      "GoalDate": "2014-04-16T00:00:00",
      "AvgActivityTime": 12
    }
  ],
  "UserSessions": [
    {
      "UserSessionId": 0,
      "DeviceGuid": "962d26a01cdef0c8",
      "DeviceSessionId": "2a0bb7a0-041d-4df6-abcb-e50483858cba",
      "DailyGoalId": 1,
      "DailyGoalDetailId": 6,
      "ActivityId": 1,
      "Start": "2014-04-16T16:10:11",
      "Stop": "2014-04-16T16:15:53",
      "TotalBeats": 0,
      "TotalKcal": 1,
      "Pace": 0.00,
      "Frequency": 1,
      "SessionDetails": [
        {
          "Speed": 0.0,
          "Step": 4,
          "Distance": 0.0,
          "Beats": 0.0033395835198462009,
          "Lat": 45.70608193,
          "Lng": 9.70917967,
          "Altitude": 298.0,
          "Orientation": 0.0,
          "Start": "2014-04-16T16:10:10",
          "Stop": "2014-04-16T16:10:11"
        },
        {
          "Speed": 0.0,
          "Step": 2,
          "Distance": 0.0,
          "Beats": 0.0033395835198462009,
          "Lat": 45.70608193,
          "Lng": 9.70917967,
          "Altitude": 298.0,
          "Orientation": 0.0,
          "Start": "2014-04-16T16:10:11",
          "Stop": "2014-04-16T16:10:12"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the relevant code that initialize and calls the mapper (this is done over an NSString):

```
        // Json decoding
        NSError *decodingError = nil;
        id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:decodedUncompressedData MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&decodingError];
        if (parsedData == nil && error) {
            NSLog(@"Error decoding json received from synchronization");
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *mappingsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        // Add DailyGoalDetails->MGRDailyGoalDetail mapping
        [mappingsDictionary setObject:[MGRDailyGoalDetail responseMapping] forKey:@"DailyGoalDetails"];
        // Add UserSessions->MGRSession mapping
        [mappingsDictionary setObject:[MGRSession responseMapping] forKey:@"UserSessions"];
        RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
        RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *dataSource = [[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:[MGRModel sharedModel].managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext cache:[MGRModel sharedModel].managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache];
        dataSource.parentOperation = mapper;
        mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = dataSource;
        NSError *mappingError = nil;
        BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
        if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
            NSLog(@"jsonMappingResult = %@",[mapper mappingResult]);
            [[[[MGRModel sharedModel] managedObjectStore] persistentStoreManagedObjectContext] save:&mappingError];
        }
```

Comment: Show the code for how you're logging in your test

Comment: @Wain I've added the information you requested. Please let me know if you need further info.

Comment: So the code looks ok. It isn't clear what isn't actually working (creating the mapping or the mapping results). It isn't clear why you're using `RKMapperOperation` directly (instead of `RKObjectManager`). Have you verified `parsedData` actually contains what you expect? And turn on trace logging and see what it says about the relationship.

Comment: @Wain I've been using ```RKMapperOperation``` because I've been following the example code there: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#performing-a-mapping - I can't paste the log because it's a huge JSON. I can put it on dropbox if you want to have a look at what happens in there. As far as I can tell there connection is being completely ignored. I tried adding a connection on the child object instead and even though the connection isn't established, at least the mapper says something about evaluating the connection that way.

Comment: Is there any chance that I should force the mapper to consume the DailyGoalDetails array first and then only after that one is mapped, process the UserSessions array so that it can find the related data?

Comment: Here's the actual JSON response: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3098924/RestKit/response.json - and here's the RestKit trace log: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3098924/RestKit/mapping.txt.zip

Comment: Can you use a gist? I can't access zip files...

Comment: Sure, here's the JSON: https://gist.github.com/tanis2000/11255933 - and here's the response (15Mb): https://gist.github.com/tanis2000/11256175

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51356/discussion-between-wain-and-valerio-santinelli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RKMapperOperation` doesn't actually do much work. Internally it uses `RKMappingOperation` and that is what makes the connections. To make it work you have 2 options:

1. Use 2 `RKMapperOperation` instances that are dependent on each other, with the session mapper running second
2. Use `RKObjectManager` to oversee the whole process

If you use mapper operation directly then you will need 2 of them so that you can explicitly control the order. In theory you can alternatively add the connection onto both mappings, so it doesn't matter which is run first (so long as they are both backed by the same MOC).